# xdmp:directory for full urls

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there something similar to xdmp:directory for traversing over documents that have uris that do not start with a "/", i.e. "http://something.other.com/documents/"? Or is there some way to get all documents where the document uri matches a regular expression?

For example, I want to pull the documents for:

- http://something.other.com/documents/a.txt
- http://something.other.com/documents/b.txt
- http://something.other.com/documents/folder/c.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cts:uri-match` should be exactly what you're looking for.  You can put a wildcarded expression in there, such as `cts:uri-match('/myDirectory/sub-dir/*.xml')`.  This will return a list of URI's as strings, and you can then get those documents in mass by doing something like (note: `fn:doc()` can take zero to many uri's):

```
let $uris as xs:string* := cts:uri-match("/you/directory/structure/*.xml")
let $docs as document-node()* := fn:docs($uris)
return $docs
```

As per Tyler's comment below, you should pass in a `cts:query` qualifier in this search if possible, for instance:

```
let $uris as xs:string* := cts:uri-match("/your/directory/structure/*.xml", (), cts:directory-query("/your/directory/structure/", "infinity"))
let $docs as document-node()* := fn:docs($uris)
return $docs
```

In the above example, the `cts:directory-query` narrows the scope a little more, and note that "infinity" will take all sub-directories to the infinite level.

Or, if they are all under a directory that you want (or multiple directories), and no wildcard is needed to further qualify the file names and such, you can so something better like:

```
cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:directory-query("/some-dir/", "infinity"))
```

But if you want to use regular expressions-esque searching, the first option is definitely your friend.

http://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/cts:uri-match

Comment: This does seem to be what you are looking for but be careful about using this function. If you don't scope it with a cts query it will do a check on all the Uris in your database and with databases that have a large amount of documents that could take a while to return. I'd look at putting a cts:directory query in the query optional perm.

Comment: Thanks @TylerReplogle, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Perfect.  I checked it out and it works, in my limited testing, on non '/' based paths as well.

Comment: The cts:uri-match runs against the URI lexicon (which needs to be enabled). It doesn't need to go to disk to crawl all forests for matching docs. I'd be curious if the cts:directory-query makes a big difference.

Comment: Also, you can feed a list of doc uris into cts:document-query, and pass the cts query into cts:search. It should scale reasonably well up to a million doc uris or more, but not endlessly.